# symfony - confirm when browser closed

Tags: symfony

Is there any symfony global parameter for confirm when user change form and close browser, or go to other page.

PS. I know how to do that in jquery / javascript, but maybe there is "native" function in symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony has nothing to do here. That's only frontend's thing to check, so only js (or any used js framework) with checking **js onclose window** event.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I thought that adding parameter to symfony form it will add js to the page..:) like I said, I know how to that in js;)

edit:

Welcome:)